# I want to auto update the list in the screen with firebase

Tags: reactjs, nestjs

My app uses Reactjs (redux, hook, context), Nestjs and Firebase. How do I create data and then auto update the list? The list will be shown in a independent screen (other computer), so I need to auto update it.

```
Nestjs:
main.ts:
const adminConfig: ServiceAccount = {
  "projectId": configService.get<string>('FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID'),
  "privateKey": configService.get<string>('FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY')
                        .replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  "clientEmail": configService.get<string>('FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL'),
};

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(adminConfig),
});

Reactjs:
firebase.js:
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "myhealthqlpkv3.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "myhealthqlpkv3",
  storageBucket: "myhealthqlpkv3.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
  appId: "xxxxx",
  measurementId: "xxxx"
};
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = firebase.default.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebaseApp ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **onSnapshot** method to listen or wait for any changes in the database or collections, and respond to the returned data as you wish.

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-v8_2

Comment: My friend tell me that I dont need the realtime database or firestore here, because there is no need for a notification. But as I can see, onSnapshot is used with Firestore?

Comment: If you are not using Firestore, use the on or once function instead. More info in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events.

Comment: Is there anyway to not use database (Realtime database and Firestore database) at all? Because my data is not saved in these database, it is saved in a seperated server.

Comment: What do you mean? According to the configuration above, your database is in firebase. Where are your data, or which database are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry, I have reupdate it, in this case I dont use realtime database or firestore database. My main database is in a seperated server. Main database here is not firebase. If I want to get data from it, I have to use api.

Comment: The database that you are using, whatever it is, should have an event emitter same as with firebase that sends a message to the database reference when the collection is updated. If this is not available or if the database does not have an API that handles this, real time update is not possible.

Comment: You might still be able to accomplish this by fetching the data once every tick, compare it to the current state, check if it changes or not, and do something based on the result. But this is a lot of assumption and is a lot more difficult and complicated that it actually sounds.

Comment: Do you mean I still need a Realtime Database(or FirestoreDatabase) ? Then I have to save the message into these database? So that the Firebase notice the message and send back to client?

Comment: Yes, probably. I might be mistaken, but I don't think you can use the Firebase/Firestore API on a different database. And it is a bit difficult to offer more help since we do not know anything about your actual database.